# Filter unique row with positional file and fixed position of the key

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I work with with KornShell Script.

I have a positional file formatted like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

X is my key 11 length and I want to filter this file with unique key constraint.

X it is an String Type which could have values like that:

```
FJUYHGRESJFYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZNXKDDYHDNKYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

I have test this command :

```
cat Stack.txt | uniq -D -s 11 > Result.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command :

```
cat Stack.txt | uniq -w 11 > Result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Say if you've got:-

```
XXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

Then you can use:-

```
while IFS=':' read field1 field2
do
    if [ $(echo "${field1}" | sed -n '/XXXXXXXXXXX/p') ]
    then
    (commands) ...
    elif [ $(echo "${field1}" | sed -n '/key2/p') ]
    then
    (other commands) ...
    fi
done
```

Comment: I haven't got a separated char and my key XXXXXXXXXXX could take different values .I need to put in my new file the uniques rows with this key

Comment: If you want to do that, you will probably need to look into something like PostgreSQL.  You can't really do proper relational work with a shell script.  I mean, yes you could do relatively simple row/column stuff, but it won't be as robust.

Answer (score 0):

I have found :)

In the command uniq there is -w parameter :

```
-w  Specifies the number of characters to compare in lines, after any characters and fields have been skipped
```

So i have create this command :

cat Stack.txt | uniq -w 11 > Result.txt